# PNG is not being rendered using PhantomJS with multiple attempts in a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, phantomjs

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var filepath = "/home/abc/" + "abc.html"; //create path to charts.html    
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // make three attempts
    console.log("hi")
    page.open(filepath, function(status) {
      console.log(status);
      //if(status !== 'success') { //if not success, make another attempt
//        continue;
  //    }

      page.render('abc.png');
      phantom.exit();
    });
}    
phantom.exit();
```

running this code like this:

```
$ phantomjs hello.js
```

Q1: I am expecting `abc.png` to be generated in my home dir. However with current code it is not generated.

Q2: Adding the commented out if block back causes the code execution to become stuck. Why so ?

Comment: Are you using PhantomJS 2?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes `$ phantomjs --version
2.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems that are intertwined.

#### 1. `continue`

`continue` is used to go to the next iteration of a loop construct such as `for` or `while`. That's not what you're doing here. There is no loop around `continue` in the local scope which means this is a syntax error.

There is a bug in PhantomJS 2 that doesn't show Syntax errors anymore and simply freezes. Run your favorite linter (jslint, jshint, eslint) to prevent such mistakes.

#### 2. `page.open()` is asynchronous

You cannot use a loop to open multiple page one after another. `page.open()` is asynchronous. By calling it, you only initiate the load. Since it doesn't block on the next iteration you will overwrite the request with a new URL and the first request will never be completed, because a for-loop is much faster than a page request.

The only page that could potentially be loaded is the last one, but ...

#### 3. Premature exiting

You're exiting too early. Since `page.open()` is asynchronous, the loop will run completely through without loading even one page completely. At the end you have a `phantom.exit()` which will exit PhantomJS immediately.

---

If you have to open a bunch of pages, use a recursive approach or a clever use of `setTimeout()`. You could also use the [async's](https://github.com/caolan/async) `series()` function to write it in a more sane way.

Example as a simple recursive function:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var filepath = "/home/abc/" + "abc.html"; //create path to charts.html    
function run(i){
    if (i <= 0) {
      return phantom.exit();
    }
    page.open(filepath, function(status) {
      console.log(status);
      if(status === 'success') { //if not success, make another attempt
        page.render('abc'+i+'.png');
      }
      run(i-1);
    });
}
run(3);
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways solve this, because there are a lot of asynchronous helper functions. One note though, Promises cannot be used, because they are not supported by PhantomJS (tested with versions 1.9.8 and 2.1.1).