# phantomjs not rendering webpage to png

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

well my code is something like this just a few lines

```
var a = "http://lnmtl.com/chapter/renegade-immortal-chapter-";
var b = 558;
var d = "rennegrade_ch";
var f = ".png";
var page = require('webpage').create();
var i = 0;
for (i = b; i < 560; i++) {
    var c = a + i;
    console.log(c);
    page.open(c, function () {
        var e = d + i + f;
        console.log(e);
        page.render(e);

    });
}
phantom.exit();
```

the webpage can be rendered individually but once i put it inside for loop all it does is print the first console output properly but the second one it skips i guess its not entering the page.open function then for loop value increases then same thing happens again I have no idea why its not entering render function i tried to put     var page = require('webpage').create();
inside for loop too but still no change

UPDATE: On another question stackoverflow.com/questions/31621577/png-is-not-being-rendered-using-phantomjs-with-multiple-attempts-in-a-loop?rq=1
it was pointed that this method wont work because of async nature of function but the example code provided in it isnt helpful enough can anyone example and i also tried set timeout as suggested in it still same thing happens so any other idea ?

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the provided solution in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31625166/1816580) on the linked question? Your code exhibits issues 2 and 3 that I described.

Comment: ah m sorry the recursive part and status variable confused me there my mistake but can u give example with set time out i tried but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For async request inside loop you should use asynchronous library so you can debug your code and don't get memory leak issue

[async-js](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) will be good in your case

`npm install async`

```
var async = require('async');
var a = "http://lnmtl.com/chapter/renegade-immortal-chapter-";
var b = 558;
var d = "rennegrade_ch";
var f = ".png";
var page = require('webpage').create();
var i = 0;
async.whilst(
  function() {
    return i < 560;
  },
  function(callback) {
    i++;
    var c = a + i;
    console.log(c);
    page.open(c, function() {
      var e = d + i + f;
      console.log(e);
      page.render(e);
      callback(null, i);
    });
  },
  function(err, n) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    phantom.exit();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `phantom.exit()` call kills the PhantomJS browser before you do any rendering.  You have to wait for the rendering to end before you can `exit()`.  You need to have some mechanism to say when the rendering is done.  I'd suggest wrapping each of your renders in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  Then using a [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all the render promises to resolve.  After they resolve, exit PhantomJS.

---

Right now, you have what is below, which does not respect the asynchronous nature of `page.open()`:

```
for (...) {
    // I probably wont finish because phantom dies almost immediately
    page.open(c, function () {
        // I won't finish running since phantom dies
        page.render(e);
    });
}
// I'm going to kill the phantom almost immediately
phantom.exit();
```

You want something like the code below, which will wait for all the renders to finish.  This will put renders of each of the sites we provide in a subdirectory "renders".

**Note:** You will need to install the [**es6-promise**](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) shim for this to work since PhantomJS does not yet support Promises.  Thanks for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853294/phantomjs-not-rendering-webpage-to-png/35853721#comment59373367_35853721) about that [Artjon B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816580/artjom-b)

```
/*jslint node:true*/
/*globals phantom, sayHello*/

"use strict";

var Promise = require("es6-Promise").Promise;

// Array of URLs that we want to render
var urlArr = [
    {
        name: "google",
        url: "http://www.google.com"
    },
    {
        name: "yahoo",
        url: "http://www.yahoo.com"
    },
    {
        name: "bing",
        url: "http://www.bing.com"
    }
];

// Map URLs to promises
var proms = urlArr.map(function (url) {
    // Return a promise for each URL
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Make a page
        var page = require("webpage").create();
        // Open the URL
        console.log("opening: " + url.name);
        page.open(url.url, function () {
            // Render the page
            page.render("render/" + url.name + ".png");
            console.log("done rendering: " + url.name);
            // Say that we are done with rendering
            resolve();
        });
    });
});

// Wait for all rendering to finish
Promise.all(proms).then(function () {
    console.log("closing phantom");
    // Exit phantom
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't support promises (tested with PhantomJS 2.1.1 and 1.9.8). You'd need a shim.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks, Artjom, corrected the code to use the es6-promise shim.  This works on my client.